# How to increment floating point numbers by 1?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python code which can help to increment the version values below by 1,expected output shows the result?I am thinking of splitting the version saving each digit ,increment the last digit by 1 and reconstruct the version,is there a way to this simply in python?

```
version1 =  1151.1
version2 =  4.1.1
version3 = 275.1.2.99
version4 = 379

next_version1 = version1 + 1
print next_version1

next_version2 = version2 + 1
print next_version2

next_version3 = version3 + 1
print next_version3

next_version4 = version4 + 1
print next_version4
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
1151.2
4.1.2
275.1.2.100
380
```

Comment: The numbers with more than one decimal digits are *not* floats. Version numbers with more than one dot are not floats, and are intended to be strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually not all the numbers are floats in this case.

You should treat it as strings and update the last element.

```py
version1 = '275.1.2.3'
version2 = '279'
version3 = '275.2.3.10'

def updateVersion(version):
    if '.' in version:
        version = version.split('.')
        version[-1] = str(int(version[-1]) + 1)
        version = '.'.join(version)
    else:
        version = str(int(version)+1)
    return version

updateVersion(version1)
updateVersion(version2)
```

Output:

```py
275.1.2.4
280
275.2.3.11
```

Comment: this fails when the version = `369`,it becomes `3610` instead of `370`

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost please read about [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Maybe that was the reason why you ask, not clear.

However, I suggest to save each part as an integer, e.g.

```
main_version_number = 1151
minor_version_number = 1
sub_version_number = 0
```

You could maybe have a data structure with those fields (a `Version` class maybe?) with appropriate methods.

Do not rely on floating point arithmetic.

Comment: if you can be more specific with an example that helps for all the cases i have  it will be helpful

Comment: Aalok gave an example, and is probably a better answer than mine. There are many ways to accomplish the task. I'm surprised though that the accepted answer is the one processing strings.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the code you outline would most certainly give a syntax error.
A number of the form `2` is an integer; `2.2`, a floating point; but a `2.2.2`, meaningless.

You are looking for tuples here. For instance,
`>>> version3 = (275,1,2,3)`
Then you would get

```
>>> version3
(275, 1, 2, 3)
```

To dirty-update only the last bit of such a tuple, you could do

```
>>> version3 = version3[:-1] + (version3[-1] + 1,)
>>> version3
(275, 1, 2, 4)
```

The reason I call this *dirty* updating is that it will not take care of carrying over into the next significant bit.

Here's a relatively simple script to do just that that I could put together in a couple of minutes. Assuming you have stored your version number as a tuple object called `version`, attempt the following:

```
new_version = version
for bit in range(len(version)):
    new_version = new_version[:-1-bit] + ((new_version[-1-bit] + 1) % 10,) + new_version[-bit:]
    if -2-bit >=0:
        new_version = new_version[-2-bit:] + (new_version[-2-bit] + (version[-2-bit] + 1) // 10,) + new_version[-1-bit:]
    elif (version[-2-bit] + 1) // 10:
        new_version = (1,) + new_version
```

Alternatively, take a look at [bumpversion](https://github.com/peritus/bumpversion), a tool that lets you take care of version-numbering within your project, with git integration.

Answer (score 0):

The variables 'version2' and 'version3' will result in a syntax error. This syntax error is caused by the fact that Python does not know of any (number) type that has several points in its value. In essence you are trying to use certain types in a way that they are not meant to be used. More specifically the floating point number is not suitable for your goals. As the name suggests a floating point number, only contains one point and that point can be placed anywhere between its digits (floating).

My advice would be to create your own type/class. This would enable you to store the version number in a way that allows for easy modification of its values and better separation of concerns in your code (i.e. that each part of your code is only concerned with one thing).

**Example**

```
class VersionNumber:
    """Represents a version number that can contain parts (major, minor, etc).""" 
    def __init__(self, *argv):
        """This is the constructor, i.e. a function that is called when you create a new VersionNumber.
        The '*argv' allows the user of this class to give a variable amount of arguments. This is why
        you can have a version number with only 1 number, and one with 4. The '*argv' is iterable."""

        #Create a class specific field, that stores all the version number parts in a list.
        self.Parts = []
        #Fill it with the supplied arguments.
        for part in argv:
            self.Parts.append(part)

    def __repr__(self):
        """This function is called when the VersionNumber needs to be displayed in the console"""
        return str(self)

    def __str__(self):
        """This function is called when the VersionNumber is parsed to a string"""
        return '.'.join(map(str,self.Parts))

    def incrementVersion(self, position, incrementAmount):
        """This function allows you to increment the version number. It does this by adjusting the list
        we have set in the constructor."""
        self.Parts[position] += incrementAmount


version1 = VersionNumber(1, 23, 45, 0)
print(version1)
#Position -1, takes the last (most right) version number part from the version number.
version1.incrementVersion(-1, 1)
print(version1)

version2 = VersionNumber(346)
print(version2)
version2.incrementVersion(-1, 2)
print(version2)
```